# Android Emulator - PC Serial Port

Tags: android-emulator

I need to prototype an Android application which communicates to external hardware using serial I/O. Can the emulator send and receive serial data over a PC's com port?

Answer (score 7):

The Android emulator itself supports this feature, I see people use
"emulator -qemu -serial COM1"   on Windows PC

or

"emulatro -qemu -serial /dev/ttyS0"  on Linux PC

I have not tried it by myself yet, but that is the way in the big picture.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/

this library will let you use Java to access the serial port on your Android device