# Using Android-emulator to test AT commands by COM from external application

Tags: c#, android-emulator, serial-port, 3g, at-command

I need send AT commands to a usb GSM modem whith C#.
The problem is that i havent no GSM modem or GSM enabled device yet to develop then i was looking for a emulator.
The only simulated GSM modem i found was that come with the Android SDK.
My problem now is sent AT commands to Android simulated GSM modem througt COM port like i need to do in my real application.
There is some way to reach COM (virtual Usb-Com) port of Android simulated GSM modem and sent AT commands to connect to internet ?

There is someone telling about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417438/hayes-at-command-support-on-android) but it cant help me.

Comment: hi, can you explain which Android SKD you used? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it can help:

[Android Emulator - PC Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246094/android-emulator-pc-serial-port)

http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/bc4919b347ce5062

Answer (score 1):

Why dont use Microsoft emulator ?

see the [Cellular Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630224.aspx) section and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx#AccessingConnectionManagerfrom%20Managed%20Code).